# Why Java doesn't a Stream that returns list of generics work?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

Why does this work:

```java
private List<Optional<Event>> createEventsStartingWith(List<Long> forwardIds, int startAt, final AnnouncementUpdatedEventPayload beforeChanges) {
    List<Optional<Event>> announcementDeletedAppEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Long forwardId : forwardIds.subList(startAt, forwardIds.size())) {
        announcementDeletedAppEvents.add(Optional.of(new AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent(forwardId, eventMapper.mapToNotificationPayload(beforeChanges))));
    }
    return announcementDeletedAppEvents;
}
```

but this doesn't work:

```
compilation error:
Required type: List<Optional<Event>>

Provided: List<Optional<AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent>>
```

```java
private List<Optional<Event>> createEventsStartingWith(List<Long> forwardIds, int startAt, final AnnouncementUpdatedEventPayload beforeChanges) {
    return IntStream.range(forwardIds.indexOf(startAt), forwardIds.size())
                .mapToObj(forwardId -> Optional.of(new AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent(forwardId, eventMapper.mapToNotificationPayload(beforeChanges))))
                .toList();
}
```

where:

```java
public class AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent extends Event{
    long Id;
    AnnouncementPayload payload;
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code

Comment: @ControlAltDel I updated AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent  class... I don't see anything else to show you... One method written in 2 ways

Comment: BTW: I've never seen a useful application of `Optional` in a collection like `List`. As a rule, it's quite natural to omit an element entirely rather than adding an empty element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [Generics are invariant in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/10871900).

Let's look at the expression you are returning:

```java
IntStream.range(forwardIds.indexOf(startAt), forwardIds.size())
        .mapToObj(forwardId -> Optional.of(new AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent(forwardId, eventMapper.mapToNotificationPayload(beforeChanges))))
        .toList();
```

Specifically, the `mapToObj` method will give you a `Stream<AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent>` and not a `Stream<Event>` because `javac` sees that it will always be an `Optional<AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent>` (instead of an `Optional<Event>`) and it tries to find the most general type and it does not propagate type information backwards through methods.

Then, `toList()` converts the result to a `List<Optional<AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent>>`. Since generics are invariant, a `List<Optional<AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent>>` is *not* a `List<Optional<Event>>`.

You can fix this issue by telling Java you just want events using an additional type paramer (you can explicitely the type used in `Optional.of`) by adding `<Event>` before the `of` (`Optional.<Event>of(...)`):

```java
return IntStream.range(forwardIds.indexOf(startAt), forwardIds.size())
        .mapToObj(forwardId -> Optional.<Event>of(new AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent(forwardId, eventMapper.mapToNotificationPayload(beforeChanges))))
        .toList();
```

Alternatively, you can cast the `AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent` to an `Event` before calling `Optional.of`:

```java
return IntStream.range(forwardIds.indexOf(startAt), forwardIds.size())
        .mapToObj(forwardId -> Optional.of((Event) new AnnouncementDeletedAppEvent(forwardId, eventMapper.mapToNotificationPayload(beforeChanges))))
        .toList();
```